# Retrieve data from database dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql

I have done some calculation using the data from `chartofaccount` table I have subtracted `SUM(debit_amount)-SUM(credit_amount)` when `coa_type="ACCOUNT_RECEIVABLE"` and `SUM(credit_amount)-SUM(debit_amount)` when `coa_type='SECURITY_DEPOSIT'` for one `customerID` but now I want that all the values will appear in one row for all`coa_type` what should I do?I had group by `coa_type` because calculation of `debit_amount` and `credit_amount` is different for different `coa_type`.Please let me know If I am not clear.

here is my query  ..

```
SELECT  
    CASE WHEN coam.`coa_type`='ACCOUNTS_RECEIVABLE'
THEN SUM(`debit_amount`)-SUM(`credit_amount`)
END AS receivable,

CASE WHEN coam.`coa_type`='SECURITY_DEPOSIT'
THEN SUM(`credit_amount`)-SUM(`debit_amount`)
END AS securitydeposit

,`customer_master`.`customer_credit_limit`
,coam.`coa_type`  ,`customer_priority`.`name`

 FROM `journal_details`  

INNER JOIN `journal`  ON `journal`.`id`=`journal_details`.`journal_id`
INNER JOIN `customer_master`  ON      `customer_master`.`code`=`journal_details`.`prefix_code`
 INNER JOIN `customer_priority` ON `customer_priority`.`id` = `customer_master`.`customer_priority_id`
INNER JOIN `chart_of_accounts`  ON `chart_of_accounts`.`id`= `journal_details`.`chart_of_accounts_id`
 INNER JOIN `chart_of_accounts_mapping` coam ON coam.`chart_of_accounts_id`= `chart_of_accounts`.`id`

 WHERE `customer_master`.`code` =(SELECT CODE FROM `customer_master`  WHERE `customer_master`.id=11) 
 GROUP BY coam.`coa_type`
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would either use a `case` on the `coa_type`  to do one or other SUM or do two queries (one per coa_type) a use an `union`.

Comment: But I used `case` on `coa_type`.and I also used MAX function but that was not  working on it also

Comment: Forget what I said, I read in the same column, not same row... Since you use a group by, you are going to need a subquery, then put the result on one row I guess.

Comment: Using my first idea could work but it's ugly, for each column, you do a `select ... where coa_type like ...`. no garranty ;)

Comment: could you show the output u r expecting?

Comment: Just say ... since you `group by coa_type` and print this column, why do you want to print the SUM of two diff `coa_type`. This doesn't seams logic at all. @Avi, He has edited is answer ;)

Comment: still its not clear to me.what he wants?  how has he merged two 2 rows to one..

Comment: No didn't edited the answer I made a sample to make you understand ;) @AxeIH..BTW I have solved my problem..And I am sorry I couldn't make you understand my problem..my fault